# Python - merge nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this data structure:

```
playlists_user1={'user1':[
               {'playlist1':{
                    'tracks': [        
                    {'name': 'Karma Police','artist': 'Radiohead', 'count': 1.0},
                    {'name': 'Bitter Sweet Symphony','artist': 'The Verve','count': 2.0}                    
                     ]
                    }
               },
               {'playlist2':{
                    'tracks': [        
                    {'name': 'We Will Rock You','artist': 'Queen', 'count': 3.0},
                    {'name': 'Roxanne','artist': 'Police','count': 5.0}                    
                     ]
                  }
                },
              ]
            }


playlists_user2={'user2':[
               {'playlist1':{
                    'tracks': [        
                    {'name': 'Karma Police','artist': 'Radiohead', 'count': 2.0},
                    {'name': 'Sonnet','artist': 'The Verve','count': 4.0}                    
                     ]
                    }
               },
               {'playlist2':{
                    'tracks': [        
                    {'name': 'We Are The Champions','artist': 'Queen', 'count': 4.0},
                    {'name': 'Bitter Sweet Symphony','artist': 'The Verve','count': 1.0}                    
                     ]
                  }
                },
              ]
            }
```

I would like to merge the two nested dictionaries into one single data structure, whose first `item` would be a `playlist key`, like so:

```
{'playlist1': {'tracks': [{'count': 1.0, 'name': 'Karma Police', 'artist': 'Radiohead'}, {'count': 2.0, 'name': 'Bitter Sweet Symphony', 'artist': 'The Verve'}]}}
```

I have tried:

```
prefs1 = playlists_user1['user1'][0]
prefs2 = playlists_user2['user2'][0]
prefs3 = prefs1.update(prefs2)
```

to no avail.

how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your playlist values are already a list of lists of dictionaries with one key (a bit obfuscated if you ask me):

```
combined = {}
for playlist in playlists_user1.values()[0]:
     combined.update(playlist)
for playlist in playlists_user2.values()[0]:
     combined.update(playlist)
```

or if you have many of these, make a list and:

```
combined = {}
for playlistlist in user_playlists:
    for playlist in playlistlist.values()[0]:
        combined.update(playlist)
```

Comment: @kabanaus using your first solution, I get `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

Comment: You have an extra list layer I missed, sec I'll update.